# Cannot connect to Wordpress MySQL on Fedora 25

Tags: wordpress, php, mysql

On Fedora 25, I want to develop a Wordpress website. Here's a summary of what I did, but I still cannot get it to work and enter Wordpress management panel:

1- I started MySQL by running
`sudo systemctl start mariadb`
2- I started Apache by running
`sudo systemctl start httpd`
3- I unzipped Wordpress 4.7.4 to `/var/www/html`. I also changed the ownership of the wordpress folder to `john:apache`.
4- I created a database in mysql:
`CREATE DATABASE mydb 
CHARACTER SET = UTF16
COLLATE = utf16_persian_ci`
5- I added a database user:
`CREATE USER 'john'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'P@ssw0rd'`
6- I created wp-config.php inside the wordpress folder by `cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php` and edited it as follows:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'mydb');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'john');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'P@ssw0rd');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf16_persian_ci');
```

Now when I open `http://localhost/wordpress` in my browser, I see a big "**Error establishing a database connection**".

When I open `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin` an error page appears saying:

`We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the mydb database.`

I do not know what I did wrong. I am user the database exists, but have no idea why Wordpress cannot connect to it.

Comment: Why are you doing a manual install rather than the recommended method of using the inbuilt installer? No need to manually input any database details, in fact by doing so you are stopping WordPress populating the SQL because in neither of your steps have you imported the SQL database that comes with WordPress... if my assumption is correct simply delete the WordPress directory and start over using the recommended method.

Comment: +1 @SimonHayter - given the complexity of WordPress, the auto install is stupidly easy.

Comment: @Simon you're right. Auto install is cool but it didn't work out for me as I guess it's typical for Linux due to its permission intricacies.

Comment: Its not typical for it not to work. If your server is having difficulties installing it then it most likely have problems using it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error says that connection to the database was OK, in addition to the above, you also need to run the following command:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO "john"@"localhost"
    -> IDENTIFIED BY "P@ssw0rd";
```

Once this is run in MySQL, Wordpress start page brings up its Welcome page.